# JSON body in the application is not being accepted but the same body is being accepted in postman

Tags: flutter, post, one-time-password

I want to send an otp http post request from flutter, I build the request and tried to send it to the server but I keep getting a server error. the problem is that I printed the same object that I send to server and copy-pasted it to postman and everything worked!

This is my code:

```
Future<dynamic> otp(
      {required String url, required int otp, required String email}) async {
    try {
      print(json.encode({"otp": otp, "email": email}));

      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(_baseURL + url),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode({"otp": otp, "email": email}),
      );
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return OtpData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        return OtpData(otp: 0000, email: email);
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

And this is the Postman request:
[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIXm3.png)

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Update the question with a screenshot of the working Postman request.

Comment: @RichardHeap I did.

Comment: There may be a difference in the headers sent. Looks like Postman is including 10, but you are just adding 1. What error do you get?

Comment: @RichardHeap it's a server error indicates that the fields are required, something from the backend side.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the Postmap request headers tab.